# Disable swarm manager from recreating new containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-swarm

I have a swarm formed of a manager and 3 workers. when one of the workers reboots the swarm managers will recreate the containers from the failed worker into the other healthy workers. I understand that this is how swarm is setup to operate but I would like to disable this feature so the manager will not recreate the containers from the rebooted worker but instead it will wait for the worker to come back again and keep the containers there.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance where you want the service to run, and you only want it to run there, you can use a [service constraint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints-constraint). For instance if you're deploying directly from the commandline:

`docker service create --name myservice --constraint 'node.hostname == node3' myimage:latest`

or in a compose file:

`version: '3'
services:
  myservice:
    image: myimage:latest
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname == node3`

Comment: thanks Mano for answering .. I was more looking to not enforce tagging or constraints so the swarm can schedule service anywhere without any constraints but prevent the manager from evacuating containers.